# Where do I enter my serial number for Adobe CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, license, serial-number, adobe-cs6

I installed CS6 in trial mode, now I got a serial, but I don't know where to enter it.

Comment: It would have been faster to contact the Abobe site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Creative Suite 6 Trial FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/uk/special/products/creativesuite/trial/faq/index.html):

> After you make your purchase, click the License This Software button on the trial screen to enter your serial number or start your subscription.